# access denied rights for start tomcat-service on windows server

Tags: tomcat, windows-services, tomcat8.5

I am using tomcat on windows server und faced a problem while updating the tomcat version.
the problem ist that the assgined user don't have the rights to start tomcat.

Here my attempts with tomcat versions:

- v8.5.43/ -> tomcat startet succesfully
- v8.5.45/ -> access denied
- v8.5.46/ -> access denied
- v8.5.47/ -> access denied
- v8.5.49/ -> access denied
- v8.5.50/ -> access denied
- v9.0.30/ -> access denied

The user has already the LogonAsService privilege.
Do you know which rights the user who start tomcat should have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the solution:

from Tomcat 8.5.44 the user must have read and exeute permissions on the Tomcat-Install-Directory.

```
ICACLS "Tomcat-Install-Directory" /grant %UserName%:(OI)(CI)(RX) /T
```

[Source](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55969)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to create an install script that calls `service.bat install`.
The installation went well but i always got this "Acces Denied" error

To fix it i added this to my script :

```
%SERVICE_NAME%.exe //US//%SERVICE_NAME% --ServiceUser LocalSystem
```